# Jquery Color Fade (Slightly Unusual Request)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following Jquery Color Fade script that introduces the hover class on "rollover" and then removes it on "rollout". Currently, the text and background both fade in and out. Ideally, using a script of this nature, I'd like only the background or background image to fade in while the text remains. I'm aware of the background-color fade option using the color Jquery plugin. However, I'd like to this to work when I use background images as well. This is why I hope to tweak the existing script. Any help on how to make only the background (whether color or image) fade in would be most appreciated.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/3/

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
    $("#menu-sample-menu li a").hover(function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
        $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);

        //On mouse-off
    }, function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
        $(this).fadeOut(300)
            .queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
        });

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="access">
    <ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-197" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-197"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/web-designer/">Web Designer</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-199"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/construction-worker/">Construction Worker</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Styles

```
#access {
    padding:0 20px;
    background:#111;
    box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#access ul {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#access li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#access ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}

#access a {
    display:block;
    padding:15px 24px;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    text-decoration:none;

}

#menu-sample-menu li {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

#menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background: orange;
}


#access li.current_page_item > a,
#access li.current-menu-item > a {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#access a span {
    color:#999;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.62em;
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Comment: where is the class `hover`??

Comment: It's listed as #menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background: orange;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add one extra span inside the li with the same text like this

```
<ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198">
         <span>Health Care Professional</span>
        <a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>


    </li>
 //...    
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/13/
OPTION 2
you can use CSS3 transition to change only the background http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/14/
OPTION 3
if you want to fade background images without repeating the text or change the html you can create an empty element with jQuery and only change the background and fade it like this

```
<li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198">
    <a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>
</li>
```

after the $(document).ready you get

```
<li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198">
    <span style="display: block;" class=""></span>
    <a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>
</li>
```

the js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#menu-sample-menu li").each(function(){ //add the empty span with the background
    $(this).prepend("<span>");
});
$("#menu-sample-menu li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("span").fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
}, function () {
    $(this).children("span").fadeOut(300)
        .queue(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
    });
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/15/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) Is there anyway to implement this change without touching the html?

Comment: you can animate background color with jQueryUI

Comment: Thx Abraham, but I'd also like the option to fade out images as well. Is there a solution that you know of that will allow me to fade out background colors and images similar to this hover class set up. The key is making sure that the text stays. Thx

Comment: I actually realized that the above solution doesn't fully address the need since you have to repeat the text twice. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this without any redundancies. Thanks in advance

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/15/](http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/15/) with that code you can fade the background image without repeating the text, you still need the extra element to use fadeIn or fadeOut because those functions animate the opacity of the element including the text so instead you animate a "background image" element leaving the text

Comment: This works great. Thanks a bunch for your help. One interesting thing I noted when I implemented this on my site was that I was referencing version 1.8.3 of Jquery which is the same as what was being used in the JS Fiddle example. However, it didn't work when I did this. I upgraded to 1.9.1 and it worked fine :)